Light stops and people don't die anymore in a book read in the 80's
This is a book I started reading around 1980 about a person walking. He finds a spaceship on a hill, enters it, and pulls a lever. From that moment on, shadows remain fixed in their positions. People did not die.

This is definitely on topic...

It's refreshing to hear about a lever in a sci-fi story that doesn't make people die.
